# threejs responsive canvas doesn't resize mesh correctly

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, three.js, resize

I am creating a basic scene on threejs and making the canvas responsive to create a full screen experience. The mesh that is inside the scene doesn't resize correctly. It is supposed to be a cube but becomes a rectangle if resized.

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

//responsive canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
});

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height);
camera.position.z = 3
scene.add(camera)


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
});

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
```

This is the expected result:

[image: This is the expected result]

but on window resize, the cube gets a weird scale:

[image: cube gets scaled in a weird way on resize]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no animation loop in your scene, you need to call `renderer.render` on `resize` manually:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

//responsive canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    
    renderer.render(scene, camera); // -> Also needed
});

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height);
camera.position.z = 3
scene.add(camera)


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
});

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
```

---

An example with an animation loop:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

scene.add(mesh);

const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

//responsive canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl');

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth;
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight;

    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
    
    // renderer.render(scene, camera); // -> Not needed since it is called in animate()
});

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height);
camera.position.z = 3
scene.add(camera)


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
});

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);

function animate(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds

  mesh.rotation.x = time * 0.5;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * 1;

  renderer.render(scene, camera); // Is called continuously here
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
```

Comment: That was it!

I removed the rotation in my case since i did not need it. So, you always need to call the renderer inside requestAnimationFrame to render properly yeah?

Comment: Yes, your scene wont update without a `renderer.render` call whenever something changes, whether on `resize` or inside `requestAnimationFrame`